# Scheduling backup in sqlserver 2005 (not able to Script Action To Job)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, backup

I'm trying to specify backup, the scripting to a new job as described in
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/930615

However, the option
Script Action to Job
is not available to me (disabled).

Could it be insufficient rights for the logged on user? Which rights must I grant the user?

Thanks,

Anders, Denmark

Answer (score 1):

What edition of SQL Server are you using?

If you are using SQL Server Express, then the option you seek is not available to you.

Comment: Hi John,

Thanks for taking the time.

I'm using SQL Server 9.0.4035 (not express), an express editition has however been installed on the server previously. In the Installed Programs, the express edition is not visible anywhere and I do believe the full version is installed correctly.

I am using Management Studio Express to access the admin options, but I expected this to be irrelevant?

Anders

Comment: Hi, you're welcome. The article you highlighted is applicable to using SQL Server Management Studio only. Have you installed/tried using SQL Server Management Studio in order to script out the new job?